# what's the difference between "src". "con" and "output"

Tags: java, eclipse

In the eclipse .classpath file, there are "src", "con" and "output" for kind, what's the difference between those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`src` : Mainly contains `.java file`, broadly speaking its the locations of `source folders`

`con` : Consider it as holding the `jars`, `libraries`,  `classpath` folders.

`output` : This contains `byte-code file`, ie. the `.class` files corresponding the the `.java` files in `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

- `src` kind has the location where java sources are present.
- `con` kind contains the locations of external archives referred to by these sources.
- `output` kind contains the compiled classes of the java sources pointed to by each `src` kind.
- `lib` kind (not in your list though) points to the location of a jar that the project is dependent on.

Consider the following java project in eclipse:

- MyProject

  - src

    - java
    - com

      - vikdor
      - domain
      - dao
  - test

    - com

      - vikdor
      - domain
      - dao

Let's say this project has dependency on spring-core-3.0.jar, spring-beans-3.0.jar, apache-commons-1.0.jar.

Then,

- src/java and src/test are `src` kind as they contain my java source files.
- the jar dependencies will be of `lib` kind each.
- if I choose to compile the java sources to `eclipse-bin` directory, that would be `output` kind.
- the JRE used by your project is of `con` kind that contains a bunch of JRE jar files (like rt.jar etc.,)

Answer (score 0):

- src - these are the locations of source folders defined in the project.  These normally contains java source files and/or resources.
- output - these are the locations of compiled files.  These are the locations where class files are placed after compilation.
- con - these are classpath container entries.  Containers are predefined collections of jars, native libraries, and/or other classpath folders.  Example containers are the Java runtime environment configured for the project and an application server runtime enviroment.